# JPA Cascade not working with Hibernate in bi-directional association?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, cascade

I have read several posts here on `cascades` with `JPA` and `hibernate`. I tried them all, but none helped.

I am trying to save a Movie object (which has `oneToMany` association with Actor). The movie object is persisted but actors object associated with movie is NOT.

Here is my `entity` class:

```
@Entity
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @Column(name="MOVIE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="MovieName")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="Date_Released")
    private Date date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="movie",fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Actor> actors=new HashSet<>();

    public Movie(){}

    public Movie(String name, Date released){
        this.name=name;
        this.date=released;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Set<Actor> getActors() {
        return actors;
    }

    public void setActors(Set<Actor> actors) {
        this.actors = actors;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return  id + " : " + name + " : " + date;
    }

    public void addActor(Actor a){
        getActors().add(a);
    }

}

@Entity
public class Actor {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ACTOR_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

@Column(name="ACTOR_NAME")
private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="ACTOR_MOVIE")
private Movie movie;


public Actor(){}

public Actor(String name){
    this.name=name;
}


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public Movie getMovie() {
    return movie;
}

public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
    this.movie = movie;
}

public String toString(){
    return name + " : " + movie.getName();
}
```

}

**Scenario 1** associating movie with Actor

```
public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

           Movie movie1 = new Movie("Mr and Mrs.Smith", new Date(2005, 6, 5));
           Actor actor3=new Actor("Brad");
           Actor actor4=new Actor("Joe"); 
           movie1.getActors().add(actor3);
           movie1.getActors().add(actor4);

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(movie1);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

     }
}
```

when I looked into the table, I see one row created in movie table and two rows in actor table. But NO association is made. That is actor_movie (`foreign column`) on actor table is null.

**Scenario 2**: associating Actor with Movie

I also tried this:

```
public class HibernateTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

   Movie movie = new Movie("Titanic", new Date(1997,12,19));
        Actor actor1=new Actor("Leo");
        Actor actor2=new Actor("Kate");
        actor1.setMovie(movie);
        actor2.setMovie(movie); 

       SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(movie1);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
}
}
```

Here I notice in the database that a row is persisted in movie table but no rows are persisted in actor table.

I don't understand why these two scenario fails? please provide explanation as to why it is going wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there is bidirectional association between Movie and Actor, you have to set both to each other.

Scenario 1

```
public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

           Movie movie1 = new Movie("Mr and Mrs.Smith", new Date(2005, 6, 5));
           Actor actor3=new Actor("Brad");
           actor3.setMovie(movie1); // Missing in ur code
           Actor actor4=new Actor("Joe"); 
           actor4.setMovie(movie1); // Missing in ur code
           movie1.getActors().add(actor3);
           movie1.getActors().add(actor4);

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(movie1);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

     }
}
```

Scenario 2

```
public class HibernateTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

   Movie movie = new Movie("Titanic", new Date(1997,12,19));
        Actor actor1=new Actor("Leo");
        Actor actor2=new Actor("Kate");
        actor1.setMovie(movie);
        actor2.setMovie(movie); 
        movie.getActors.add(actor1); // missing in ur code
        movie.getActors.add(actor2); // missing in ur code

       SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(movie1);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
}

}
```

Hope this helps.

For more information, read my blog [Here](http://morejava4u.blogspot.com/2013/09/one-to-many-relationship-in-hibernate.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the blog. I am reading it now. I have another question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107553/should-both-sides-of-onetomany-relationship-in-a-bi-directional-association-be-u please help if you can

Comment: I just read your blog: what I do here is same as what you posted in your blog: In your blog, you create two address objects and attach it to the employee object. In my scenario 1 above, I create two actors and attach it to the Movie object. Do you see my point?

Comment: But you didnt do reverse way. See the line I commented with // Missing in ur code. Those lines were missing in your scenario 1.

Comment: you didn't do reverse way in your blog too. you establish only one way. That is you create two objects and attach it to employee object. you DID NOT do reverse way either.

Comment: Search workAddress.setEmployee(emp); and residentAddress.setEmployee(emp); in my blog. It is there.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that. so is it always necessary two save both ways!

Comment: Yes it is always necessary. Accepting answer would be helpful. :)